# glPointSize(...) no longer usable in newer OpenGL versions?

Tags: opengl

I observe that whether I enable or disable `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`,  `glPointSize(...)` in my main program is always ignored and shader code line `gl_PointSize = ...` always determines the size of points.

**Is that the expected behavior on newer OpenGL versions, or do I have to suspect a bug in my code?**

Comment: What is "kernel code"?

Comment: Shader code of course ;-)

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL 4.5 spec is very clear that:

> If program point size mode is disabled, the derived point size is  specified with the command
>
> ```
> void PointSize(float size);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Program point size mode is enabled and disabled by calling **Enable** or **Disable** with *target* `PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`.

So it's either a bug in the implementation or in your code you didn't show.